# Llenar DIV con Javascrip

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy trabajando en una página web donde llenaré 3 tarjetas con datos de una base de datos, estoy utilizando JavaScript para realizar este procedimiento, pero no logro obtener los datos del array, pues me aparecen como "undefined" cuando recorro el array.

El código de la página HTML donde irán los datos de las tarjetas:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="cardsPJ">
<!--Aquí debe de ir las tarjetas.-->
</div>
```

El código de JS que realiza la solicitud:

```js
$.ajax({
            url: 'taskVerifyPjs.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(response));
                let personajes = JSON.parse(response);
                let plantilla = '';
                personajes.forEach(JNombre => {
                    console.log(personajes.Skin);
                    console.log(personajes.JNombre);
                    console.log(personajes);
                    plantilla += `
                    <div class="card  ml-3" style="width: 18rem;" align="center"><br>
                    <img src="img/skin/${personajes.Skin}.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="width: 200px;" alt="">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">${personajes.JNombre}</h2>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Ingresar</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    `
                });
                $('#cardsPJ').html(plantilla);
            }
        });
```

Por último el código de PHP:

```php
    include('dbcon.php');

        $id = $_COOKIE['ck_log_id'];
        $comprobarPJS = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pcu_cuentas WHERE PlayerID='$id'");

        $json = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comprobarPJS)){
            $json[] = array(
                'Skin' => $row['Skin'],
                'JNombre' => $row['JNombre']
            );
        }

        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
```

Estoy utilizando tantos "console.log" para intentar encontrar el error, y el error está en que cuando entro a personajes.JNombre (por ejemplo) me lo marca como indefinido y no entiendo por qué, porque al hacer el console.log del personajes, me muestra el arreglo...

Mostraré el resultado de todos los console.log:
[image: Resultado del console.log en general]

¿Alguien podría decirme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu loop [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) esta mal, debería recibir en el primer parámetro de la `callback` el item(en este caso cada objeto del array) que vas a `iterar`.
Entonces dentro de la función usas el item para acceder a cada una de las propiedades de tu objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
personajes.forEach(personaje => {
  console.log(personaje.Skin);
  console.log(personaje.JNombre);
  console.log(personaje);
  ...
})
```

Dentro del `forEach` estoy usando la key `personaje` para usarlo como item de iteración, este item representa cada elemento de tu Array.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, la verdad es que llevo casi 12 horas programando y ya sólo miro el código por encima sin analizar nada, pero ahora está funcionando... Muchas gracias hermano.